# Why do I get a syntax error with DBD::SQLite even though my version of SQLite supports `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`?

Tags: perl, sqlite

I am using SQLite v3  to write a Perl script. The sqlite version is 3.3.6.

When I run sqlite on the command line it works. But when I do the same thing in Perl it raises this error

> DBD::SQLite::db do failed: near "NOT": syntax error(1) at dbdimp.c line 268 at file line 2675.

This is what I do on the console:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.3.6
sqlite> create table if not exists  DATA_STATUS_VALUE (TYPE TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Seq INTEGER);
sqlite> .tables AllJobs            LOCKSTAT_VALUE     test_run12_data
DATA_STATUS_VALUE  STATUS_VALUE       test_run12_lock
```

The version of SQLite I'm using supports `IF NOT EXISTS`, so why am I getting an error?

This is my Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
my $driver = "SQLite";

$database = "test.db";
$dsn      = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
$dbh      = DBI->connect( $dsn, undef, undef, { RaiseError => 1 } );

$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA_STATUS_VALUE (TYPE TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Seq INTEGER);");
```

Comment: Which version of SQLite is DBD::SQLite using? `perl -E'use DBD::SQLite; say $DBD::SQLite::sqlite_version'`

Comment: DB<3> print $DBD::SQLite::sqlite_version
3.1.3

Comment: is there a way to select sqlite version by perl. I cannot install anything on the system

Comment: @east.charm [DBD::SQLite comes bundled with its own version of SQLite.](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#SQLITE-VERSION) I think you'll have to re-compile it if you want to use a different version.

Comment: Was `IF NOT EXISTS` supported with 3.1.3?  If you upgrade DBD::SQLite to the latest (1.50), it'll use sqlite 3.10.2.

Comment: Re "*I cannot install anything on the system*", That's clearly not true since you've demonstrated the ability to install a script. I suspect you'd have no problems installing this Perl module either. It's not like special permissions are needed.

Comment: Thanks but can I ask you how to load that module "sqlite_version 3.10.1"?

Comment: Looks like `IF NOT EXISTS` was [added in SQLite 3.3.0](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), so you should upgrade DBD::SQLite as ikegami suggested. The best way to upgrade depends on how you installed it in the first place: if you installed via a package manager, try to find an updated package; if you installed via CPAN, run `cpan DBD::SQLite`; if your sys admin installed it for you, ask them to update it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: *"you should upgrade `DBD::SQLite`"* Is that the answer? Please post it

Comment: @east.charm: Even with all of your charm, you don't seem to be trying very hard to get this problem solved. While you may struggle with the English language, I am sure you knew that the `sqlite3` dialogue that you posted didn't look much like what appeared on your terminal. It's crazy when the person with the problem isn't trying as hard as the people who are trying to help him. This is a place where you can ask for programming help; it's not a forum for free solutions. I doubt if sloppy phrasing and layout are acceptable wherever in the east you may be from. Please try a lot harder in future

Comment: @Borodin I was going to let ikegami answer since he said it first, but I guess that doesn't matter; converted my comment to an answer. Ironically, I was reading [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320364/176646) when I left that comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The version of SQLite I'm using supports IF NOT EXISTS, so why am I getting an error?

Because DBD::SQLite isn't using the version of SQLite you already had installed. DBD::SQLite comes bundled with [its own version of SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#SQLITE-VERSION); it will use the bundled version unless you tell it to use another version when you compile it.

You can find out the version of SQLite that DBD::SQLite is using by running:

```
perl -MDBD::SQLite -le'print $DBD::SQLite::sqlite_version'
```

Support for `CREATE TABLE ... IF NOT EXISTS` was [added to SQLite in v3.3.0](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html). You should upgrade DBD::SQLite, since the newest version (1.50) comes bundled with SQLite 3.10.2.